# Why my flatlist is filtered for a second only

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am creating a restaurant app in which I am trying to filter my flatlist based on the category being selected. At the initial point when the app is open and no category is selected flatlist display all categories data but when I click on any category the flatlist displays the filtered data just for a second but then again it displays all categories data

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { COLORS, icons, SIZES, images, FONTS } from '../constants';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';



const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

const [menu, setMenu] = useState(null)

const reference = firebase
    .app()
    .database('https://bm-restaurant-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/')
    .ref('/Menu/');

reference.on('value', snapshot => {
    setMenu(Object.values(snapshot.val()));
});


const categoryData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Rolls",
        icon: icons.ch_roll,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Burgers",
        icon: icons.burgers,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Bar B Q",
        icon: icons.barbq,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "CH\nHandi",
        icon: icons.ch_handi,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "CH\nKarhai",
        icon: icons.ch_karahi,
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Mutton",
        icon: icons.mutton_karahi,
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: "Fish",
        icon: icons.fish,
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: "Dal\nSabzi",
        icon: icons.dal,
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        name: "Paratha",
        icon: icons.paratha,
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Sand\nWiches",
        icon: icons.sandwich,
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "French\nFries",
        icon: icons.french_fries,
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Drinks",
        icon: icons.cold_drinks,
    },

]


const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null)


function onSelectCategory(category) {
    //filter restaurant
    let menuList = menu.filter(menu => parseInt(menu.category) == (category.id))
    setMenu(menuList)
    setSelectedCategory(category)
}


function renderMainCategories() {
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    padding: SIZES.padding,
                    paddingBottom: SIZES.padding * 2,
                    backgroundColor: (selectedCategory?.id == item.id) ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.white,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginRight: SIZES.padding,
                    borderRadius: 40,
                    ...styles.shadow
                }}
                onPress={() => onSelectCategory(item)}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        borderRadius: 30,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: (selectedCategory?.id == item.id) ? COLORS.white : COLORS.lightGray
                    }}>
                    <Image
                        source={item.icon}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        style={{
                            height: 45,
                            width: 45
                        }} />
                </View>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        marginTop: SIZES.padding,
                        color: (selectedCategory?.id == item.id) ? COLORS.white : COLORS.black,
                        ...FONTS.body4
                    }}>{item.name}</Text>

            </TouchableOpacity>
        )

    }
    return (
        <View style={{ padding: SIZES.padding * 2 }}>
            <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h1 }}>Categories</Text>

            <FlatList
                data={categories}
                horizontal
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: SIZES.padding * 2, paddingLeft: 2 }} />
        </View>
    )
}

function renderRestaurantList() {
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ margin: 8, width: (SIZES.width * 0.5 - 24), height: 200 }}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Restaurant', {
                    item,
                    currentLocation
                })}>

                {/* Image */}
                <Image
                    source={icons.burgers}
                    style={{
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        borderRadius: SIZES.radius
                    }}
                />
                <View
                    style={{
                        padding: SIZES.padding,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        bottom: 0,
                        height: 60,
                        backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
                        width: '100%',
                        borderRadius: 25,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        ...styles.shadow
                    }}>
                    <Text style={{ ...FONTS.body4, color: COLORS.black, textAlign: 'center' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ ...FONTS.body3, color: COLORS.primary }}>Rs. {item.price}</Text>

                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        )

    }
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={menu}
            numColumns={2}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.name}`}
            min-height={4}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            contentContainerStyle={{
                paddingLeft: 8,
                paddingRight: 8

            }} />

    )
}

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        {renderMainCategories()}
        {renderRestaurantList()}
    </SafeAreaView>
)

}
```

initial state ss

[image]

category selected ss

[image]

after 1 second ss

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not re-rendering the flatlist that's why its happening.

Flatlists are pure components and they need a way to know if it needs to re-render. Luckily we have ***extraData*** prop for flatlist, pass your data state to it and it will re-render.